# Visual Studio 2022 Mac: How to Compile SASS?

Tags: visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

Is there a method to compile SASS files on Visual Studio 2022 for Mac? In the Windows version I had installed an extension to do this, but was unable to find something similar for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get "Live Sass Compiler" as extension on VSCode. It should works also for mac. Then you can compile by clicking on "watch Sass" at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: Extensions for Visual Studio Code will also work for Visual Studio?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point that you was on VS 2022. My apologise.